# Performance of like 'query%' on multimillion rows, postgresql

Tags: postgresql

We have a table with 10 million rows. We need to find first few rows with like 'user%' .

This query is fast if it matches at least 2 rows (It returns results in 0.5 sec). If it doesn't find any 2 rows matching with that criteria, it is taking at least 10 sec. 10 secs is huge for us (since we are using this auto suggestions, users will not wait for so long to see the suggestions.)

Query: `select distinct(name) from user_sessions where name like 'user%' limit 2;`

In the above query, the `name` column is of type `citext` and it is indexed.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you're working on performance, start by [`explain`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-explain.html)ing your query. That'll show the the query optimizer's plan, and you can get a sense of how long it's spending doing various pieces. In particular, check for any full table scans, which mean the database is examining every row in the table.

Since the query is fast when it finds something and slow when it doesn't, it sounds like you are indeed hitting a full table scan. I believe you that it's indexed, but since you're doing a `like`, the standard string index can't be used efficiently. You'll want to check out [`varchar_pattern_ops`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/indexes-opclass.html) (or `text_pattern_ops`, depending on the column type of `name`). You create that this way:

```
CREATE INDEX ON pattern_index_on_users_name ON users (name varchar_pattern_ops)
```

After creating an index, check `EXPLAIN query` to make sure it's being used. `text_pattern_ops` [doesn't work with the `citext` extension](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105244/index-on-column-with-data-type-citext-not-used), so in this case you'll have to index and search for `lower(name)` to get good case-insensitive performance:

```
CREATE INDEX ON pattern_index_on_users_name ON users (lower(name) text_pattern_ops)
```

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE lower(name) like 'user%' LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply.  I have tried varchar_pattern_ops and it is working fine for varchar type, the problem is still there for citext type. Unfortunately we cant change the citext type to varchar.

Comment: You'll need to index and search for `lower(name)` then

Comment: Thanks again for your kind help. It worked for all the columns except for primary key column. It is not allowing me to add such an index for promary key column.

Comment: Primary keys can only be made of naked columns. If you need a patterned, case-insensitive index there, you must make a duplicate, non-primary index.